# При недоступности некоторых хостов ansible стал выполнять только первый плейбук

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, ansible

На прошлой неделе такого ещё не было (ну или я очень сильно был невнимателен). На этой - заметил только сегодня. Если в inventory-файле закаментить те хосты, которые потушены, то `ansible-playbook -i ./inventory test-01.yml test-02.yml` проходит нормально.

Куда копать, какие переменные менять?

`ubuntu 16.04`
`ansible 2.4.2.0`

Comment: Я по ролям раскидываю, что нужно сделать, в плейбук идет список и ничего больше. Пока не было проблем. А у вас, что там благроднейший?

Comment: Ansible начал изучать очень недавно и до ролей пока не добрался. Поэтому запускаю те плейбуки, которые нужны вот прям щас вот прям для той машины.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по [коду](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.0/lib/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py#L186), уже в версии 2.0 было такое поведение – если какие-то ошибки по итогам плейбука, то из цикла вываливаемся:

```
    # if the last result wasn't zero, break out of the playbook file name loop
    if result != 0:
        break
```

Comment: А как мне тогда в подсеть кидать задачи? У меня есть диапазон `10.10.2.*-10.10.3.*` и там машины то добавляются, то исчезают.

Comment: А в чем профит указывать несколько плейбуков одновременно?

Comment: Ответил выше в каменте к своему вопросу.